# At the bottom of the scroll bar, selenium webdriver is throwing an exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is a pop-up window that should be scrolled down to locate all the elements. 
At the bottom of the scroll bar, webdriver exception is thrown. How to check the position of the scroll bar or handle this exception.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the scroll is. Well at least if it's not in iframe. You can operate with scrollTop and scrollHeight on the scrollable div. You may google for scrolling in browsers there're a ton of answered in stackoverflow

Comment: Actually, I want to scroll the pop-up window one click at a time. Thanks

Comment: Is there any element on the pop up which you can use a reference to scroll?
If its present you can scroll to that element.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I don't have such an element. Elements are loaded while scrolling. So, if there is a way to check the scroll bar reach its end position, then I can scroll the bar and locate the populated element and check again whether canScroll() method, if it is yes, click scrollBar() method. I want to code that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can check using -
window.scrollBy(0, 50); // Scroll 50px

```
// check loader present 
//if yes then call method that waits till loader get disppers 
window.scrollBy(0, 50); // Scroll 50px 

// scroll again until loader present
// stop loop when you do not get LoaderElement. That may be your end of scroll
```